# Paragraph shifts up when mouse hover effect takes place on image

Tags: html, css, hover, size, css-position

I'm making a website for a school project. I have made 3 social media buttons with a change in size while a hover occurs. However, the paragraph above these buttons changes position when they get bigger in size. Is there a way for my paragraph to stay the same and not move even when my images get bigger?

```
<div class="maptexte">
            <p>Avez-vous besoin d'aide? Voulez-vous laisser un commentaire? Contactez-nous en tout temps grâce aux
                adresses mentionnées ci-dessous</p>
            <p>Adresse: 5505 Boul St-Laurent #2000, Montréal, QC H2T 1S6</p>
            <p>Téléphone: (514) 490-2000</p>

            <div class="sociaux">
                <div class="icones">
                <a href=""><img id="facebook" src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                <a href=""><img id="insta" src="images/insta.png" alt="ig"></a>
                <a href=""><img id="twitter" src="images/twitter.png" alt="tw"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</html>


#facebook:hover {
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
}

#insta:hover {
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
}

#twitter:hover {
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
}
```

Comment: You need to include what you have already tried to solve the problem in your post. Also, for this a screenshot of before and after would help.

Comment: Given your above code, the images seem to stay in place correctly. Are you sure your example shows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use *transform* property:

```
#facebook:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked exactly how i wanted it to. I am fairly new to programming and was unaware that i could use this property.